# Removing Duplicates in LISTAGG

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, listagg

In the query below, I used the LISTAGG function to aggregate certificate names I.e. JPM_DESCR90 . However , now I'm trying to find a way to remove all the duplications in the row, and reducing the space between the values in the All_ CERTIFICATIONS column. For the duplications , I've used the distinct function i.e. LISTAGG( DISTINCT C.JPM_DESCR90,',') as well as a number of other functions but none of them seem to  work

```
SELECT A.EMPLID, A.JOBCODE, A.JOBCODE_DESCR, A.EMPL_STATUS, A.LOCATION, A.LOCATION_DESCR, A.NAME, E.EMAILID, B.EMPLID, E.OPRID, MAX( TO_CHAR(C.JPM_DATE_3,'YYYY-MM-DD')) AS Latest_Certification_Date ,LISTAGG( C.JPM_DESCR90,',') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY C.JPM_DESCR90) AS All_Certifications 
  FROM    PS_NPS_VIEW_ALL A, (PS_PERSON_NAME B LEFT OUTER JOIN  PS_NPS_LIC_VW_RPT C ON  B.EMPLID = C.EMPLID ), PSOPRDEFN E
  WHERE ( A.EFFDT =
        (SELECT MAX(A_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_NPS_VIEW_ALL A_ED
        WHERE A.EMPLID = A_ED.EMPLID
          AND A.EMPL_RCD = A_ED.EMPL_RCD
          AND A_ED.EFFDT <= SYSDATE)
    AND A.EFFSEQ =
        (SELECT MAX(A_ES.EFFSEQ) FROM PS_NPS_VIEW_ALL A_ES
        WHERE A.EMPLID = A_ES.EMPLID
          AND A.EMPL_RCD = A_ES.EMPL_RCD
          AND A.EFFDT = A_ES.EFFDT)
     AND A.EMPLID = B.EMPLID
     AND A.EMPLID = E.EMPLID
     AND A.PER_ORG = 'EMP'
     AND A.EMPL_STATUS='A'
     AND A.PAYGROUP NOT IN ('SUM','CWR'))
  GROUP BY A.EMPLID, A.JOBCODE,A.JOBCODE_DESCR, A.EMPL_STATUS, A.LOCATION, A.LOCATION_DESCR, A.NAME, E.EMAILID, B.EMPLID, E.OPRID;
```

Another thing I tried was to use a nested select statement.

```
SELECT A.EMPLID, A.JOBCODE,A.JOBCODE_DESCR, A.EMPL_STATUS, A.LOCATION, A.LOCATION_DESCR, A.NAME, E.EMAILID, B.EMPLID, E.OPRID,
LISTAGG(C.JPM_DESCR90,','on overflow truncate with count) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY C.JPM_DESCR90)  from (select unique JPM_DESCR90 JPM_DESCR90   
                  from PS_NPS_LIC_VW_RPT C  
                 where A.EMPLID = F.EMPLID)) JPM
  FROM PS_NPS_VIEW_ALL A, (PS_PERSON_NAME B LEFT OUTER JOIN  PS_NPS_LIC_VW_RPT C ON  B.EMPLID = C.EMPLID ), PSOPRDEFN E
  WHERE ( A.EFFDT =
        (SELECT MAX(A_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_NPS_VIEW_ALL A_ED
        WHERE A.EMPLID = A_ED.EMPLID
          AND A.EMPL_RCD = A_ED.EMPL_RCD
          AND A_ED.EFFDT <= SYSDATE)
    AND A.EFFSEQ =
        (SELECT MAX(A_ES.EFFSEQ) FROM PS_NPS_VIEW_ALL A_ES
        WHERE A.EMPLID = A_ES.EMPLID
          AND A.EMPL_RCD = A_ES.EMPL_RCD
          AND A.EFFDT = A_ES.EFFDT)
     AND A.EMPLID = B.EMPLID
     AND A.EMPLID = E.EMPLID
     AND A.PER_ORG = 'EMP'
     AND A.EMPL_STATUS='A'
     AND A.PAYGROUP NOT IN ('SUM','CWR'))
  GROUP BY A.EMPLID, A.JOBCODE,A.JOBCODE_DESCR, A.EMPL_STATUS, A.LOCATION, A.LOCATION_DESCR, A.NAME, E.EMAILID, B.EMPLID, E.OPRID;
```

The above syntax gives the  following error

Error at Command Line : 3 Column : 44
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:
*Action:

I then tried regex_replace to remove duplicates.

```
SELECT  A.EMPLID,
RTRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(
           (listagg(Num2,'-') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY C.JPM_DESCR90) OVER() ), 
           '([^-]*)(-\1)+($|-)', 
           '\1\3'), '-') C.JPM_DESCR90 ,A.JOBCODE,A.JOBCODE_DESCR, A.EMPL_STATUS, A.LOCATION, A.LOCATION_DESCR, A.NAME, E.EMAILID, B.EMPLID, E.OPRID
  FROM PS_NPS_VIEW_ALL A, (PS_PERSON_NAME B LEFT OUTER JOIN  PS_NPS_LIC_VW_RPT C ON  B.EMPLID = C.EMPLID ), PSOPRDEFN E
  WHERE ( A.EFFDT =
        (SELECT MAX(A_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_NPS_VIEW_ALL A_ED
        WHERE A.EMPLID = A_ED.EMPLID
          AND A.EMPL_RCD = A_ED.EMPL_RCD
          AND A_ED.EFFDT <= SYSDATE)
    AND A.EFFSEQ =
        (SELECT MAX(A_ES.EFFSEQ) FROM PS_NPS_VIEW_ALL A_ES
        WHERE A.EMPLID = A_ES.EMPLID
          AND A.EMPL_RCD = A_ES.EMPL_RCD
          AND A.EFFDT = A_ES.EFFDT)
     AND A.EMPLID = B.EMPLID
     AND A.EMPLID = E.EMPLID
     AND A.PER_ORG = 'EMP'
     AND A.EMPL_STATUS='A'
     AND A.PAYGROUP NOT IN ('SUM','CWR'))
  GROUP BY  A.EMPLID, CERT, A.JOBCODE,A.JOBCODE_DESCR, A.EMPL_STATUS, A.LOCATION, A.LOCATION_DESCR, A.NAME, E.EMAILID, B.EMPLID, E.OPRID;
```

And I got the following error:

Error at Command Line : 5 Column : 27
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:
*Action:

Then I tried Paritions

```
    SELECT A.EMPLID, A.LOCATION_DESCR, A.NAME, E.EMAILID, B.EMPLID, 
    E.OPRID,LISTAGG(C.JPM_DESCR90,',') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY  A.EMPLID) 
    FROM(
    SELECT *, A.EMPLID, C.JPM_DESCR90 ,row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY A.EMPLID, 
    C.JPM_DESCR90 ORDER BY A.EMPLID) as rn
    FROM PS_NPS_VIEW_ALL A, (PS_PERSON_NAME B LEFT OUTER JOIN  PS_NPS_LIC_VW_RPT 
    C ON  B.EMPLID = C.EMPLID ), PSOPRDEFN E
    WHERE ( A.EFFDT =
        (SELECT MAX(A_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_NPS_VIEW_ALL A_ED
        WHERE A.EMPLID = A_ED.EMPLID
          AND A.EMPL_RCD = A_ED.EMPL_RCD
          AND A_ED.EFFDT <= SYSDATE)
    AND A.EFFSEQ =
        (SELECT MAX(A_ES.EFFSEQ) FROM PS_NPS_VIEW_ALL A_ES
        WHERE A.EMPLID = A_ES.EMPLID
          AND A.EMPL_RCD = A_ES.EMPL_RCD
          AND A.EFFDT = A_ES.EFFDT)
     AND A.EMPLID = B.EMPLID
     AND A.EMPLID = E.EMPLID
     AND A.PER_ORG = 'EMP'
     AND A.EMPL_STATUS='A'
     AND A.PAYGROUP NOT IN ('SUM','CWR'))
     ORDER BY A.EMPLID)
     WHERE rn=1
  GROUP BY A.EMPLID, A.JOBCODE,A.JOBCODE_DESCR, A.EMPL_STATUS, A.LOCATION, 
  A.LOCATION_DESCR, A.NAME, E.EMAILID, B.EMPLID, E.OPRID;
```

And got the following error:

ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 2 Column: 15

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You haven't told use your version of Oracle - please always include it. It's **important** for this question! You say you've tried solutions `but none of them seem to work`. Having the actual error messages would also be of **great** benefit - without them, we're flying blind! Look [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/19c/listagg-distinct-19c), [here](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_HT1O85E4BHSBWN93G1B3M8SI2.html) and [here](https://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/2012/04/07/oracle-11gr2-within-group/).

Comment: `LISTAGG(distinct)` was implemented in newer versions of Oracle.  You may need to upgrade the DB first.  What version of the DB are you using?

Comment: @MichaelKutz@Vérace Its version 12.c . So the distinct version would not work

Comment: You should edit your question to add the 12 version tag

Comment: @Joe W Thank You!